# The method 'RaisedButton' isn't defined for the type '_ReAssignTaskState'

Tags: flutter

[image]
The method 'RaisedButton' isn't defined for the type '_ReAssignTaskState'.

Answer (score 0):

the `RaisedButton` widget is Deprecated.
instead of it, use `ElevatedButton` widget

```
ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () {},
child: YourWidget(),
)
```